# How to give access custom module to individual users?

Tags: 7, users

I have a custom modules name "Employee Entry" and i want that module show only some of the users under a specific role. Like if i have a role office then i want there is few people who can access the content of that module. There is a by default option to give access to whole role but there is no option to give access for specific users.

Comment: What specifically do you want to give/limit access to? A listing page, or individual node/entity pages?

Comment: i want to give limit access to this url http://example.com/users-add-form

Comment: This form is basically for data entry and i want in a specific role only few users assigned for data entry

Comment: Creating a new role and assigning the users/access to that would be the best solution

Comment: but i need only one role and give specific permissions to the specific users under this role

Comment: Why though? If you implement it for specific users you still need to maintain that relationship somewhere, why not use the built-in mechanisms instead of implementing it yourself or relying on another module?

Comment: Clive is correct. Creating a role and assigning that role to users it the Drupal way.

Comment: see i am thinking about client prospective, i have create the client role named subadmin which have authority to assign node permission as per user similarly i want to give a another authority to assign module as per user

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach here would be to implement [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7.x) to define permissions/a set of permissions to give your user roles specific access.

The [Example](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module has some good [info on how to use and validate permissions](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/field_permission_example/field_permission_example.module?h=7.x-1.x) with hook_permission in your code.

If you want to restrict certain users, the easiest approach is to create an additional role with those specific things and assign the desired users to that role.